# UITabBarItem does not register click on the icon

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have four `UITabBarItem`'s. Each has a label and custom icon. My `AppDelegate` uses the `UITabBarDelegate` protocol and every click on a tabbaritem is logged to the console so I can see what is happening.

The only way to select a tabbaritem is to click on the label. If I click anywhere else on the button area, including the icon, nothing happens at all.

Have you come across anything similar?

Comment: Are you getting the events for the click even if its on the image?

Comment: No, I only get events for clicks on the label.

Comment: Can you check again and if possible try to create the tab bar again.

Comment: Is there anything special about your custom images, they're just .png files?

Comment: I tried removing the tabbar and created a new one, but the problem persists.

Comment: After some more testing I have noticed that is not actually the label but the bottom half of the tabbaritem that is clickable. But only the bottom half.

Comment: I stumbled on the solution, see original question.

Comment: Please put your answer as an answer, not just editing the question - then you can accept it and everyone googling for this problem can see that it's solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the issue. Whenever a tab was clicked and a new view was programatically inserted, that view was placed on top of the tabbar, but since it's background was transparent I could not see it. So half of the tab bar was covered by another view. By making sure to bringSubviewToFront: the problem could be solved. Thank you everyone who tried to help.